# Bash script to run Python Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, bash, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to write a Bash script so that I can run my program on a double click. The program uses tkinter and the GUI is the only thing I need to see. My bat file is the following:

```
python BudgetGUI.py &
```

This runs the code and successfully prints any print statements I have throughout my code but it never opens up the GUI. It simply runs through and closes immediately.

How can I modify the bash script to run the GUI?

Thanks in advance!

*Edit* Solutions for both mac and pc would be great, though at the moment I am on PC. I am working in Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call to `mainloop()`. I can't say for sure without seeing your code, but probably you need to add `root.mainloop()` to the bottom.

You don't need a bash or bat file. For your mac, just add a shebang and make the file executable. For Windows, add a shebang and associate the file with py.exe.

If you want to suppress the command line from popping up along with the GUI, rename your file with a .pyw extension.

Comment: So...one problem I have is that my code doesn't use any classes. I am still pretty fuzzy on object oriented programming so I sort of just forced it work without using classes. If I run the script from IDLE, the GUI and shell pop up fine. Any workarounds to this or did I dig myself into a hole?

Comment: classes have nothing to do with this

Comment: Oh. I guess I was confused. I don't have "root.mainloop()" in my code yet it still runs. If I simply added that to the end of my script, how could I implement what you are suggesting?

Comment: I added the mainloop just now to the bottom and the bash script worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: IDLE cheats and adds that line for you (sorta). Outside of IDLE you need to add it yourself.

Comment: And as I said, you don't need the bash script. Run the file directly. Not really any problem with using a bash script, but why add steps you don't need?

Comment: For some reason, my python is a little messed up on my PC. Double clicking the file opens the IDLE script, not the shell. I was never able to figure out the problem and eventually found this workaround.

Comment: As I said, you need to associate the file with py.exe. Currently it's associated with IDLE. I think you can set that in the "open with" dialog.

Comment: You are really saving me so much today. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use root.mainloop() at the end, but you could have used another name instead of root. Go check one of the first line where you wrot root = Tk() of something else like window = Tk() or any othe name, so that you put window.mainloop() at the end or any other name you gave to the object born from Tk() class.

Answer (score 0):

**Make the window made with tkinter stay out of IDLE***

if you have

```
root = Tk()
```

at the end put

```
root.mainloop()
```

if you have another name for that like:

```
window1 = Tk()
```

then, at the end put

```
window1.mainloop()
```

and so for any name you gave to the istance of Tk()

> ***A little example***

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window:
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text = "Ciao").pack()


app = Window()
app.root.mainloop()
```

***Python 2***

The code above is for python 3.
For python 2 you just need to change the first line (Tkinter with T, not t)

```
import Tkinter as tk
```